# How do I make the text centered in the image, and how do I make it bold?

Tags: texmaker

```
\begin{picture}(10,20)
\put(40,00){\includegraphics[width=50mm]{box.png}} %% OVERVIEW
\put(50,10) {1. OVERVIEW}
\end{picture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Routine coding. Use this:

```
\put(40,10) {\makebox[50mm][c]{\textbf{1. OVERVIEW}}}
```